# Send alert from idea object when idea gets 100 points

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, ideas

Can i force sales force to alert management whenever an idea gets 100 points. as far as i know it does not support workflows, neither triggers. at least that's what documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't create workflows based on the score. Even the SFDC Documentation says you should use the comments or reports as a means to accomplish tracking on Ideas: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=ideas_tips.htm&language=en

But you can write a trigger. I won't go into details, because I don't know if updating the `Vote Total` or `VoteScore` will actually fire triggers.

Comment: Thank you Bradley, i am not sure it would fire any triggers, documentation says it only work on comments. i can however create a custom report based on an idea's vote score but it's not what i am asked to do. )))

Comment: One option is to write a scheduled batch job that sends out emails or notifications nightly when Ideas reach a certain score.

Comment: You may be able to write a report subscription to send a daily email of Ideas over a certain pt level.